# How to expand the MPVolumeView route button area?

Tags: ios, objective-c, apple-tv, airplay

I am currently using MPVolume to stream audio from my app to Apple TV.
MPVolume has route button and I want to expand the touching area of this.

```
UIButton *button;
for (id object in self.volumeView.subviews) {
    if ([object isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]]) {
        button = object;
    }
}
```

I use snippet code above to catch up this button and set the new frame for it but it does not work.

[image]

Comment: @AlanQuinn I think problem is where you change its frame. After you update new frame, button's frame can be updated by system. Did you try to observer button frame and update it each time frame changed?

Comment: I tried it and it doesn't work

Comment: @AlanQuinn How about override containerView's `touchesBegan:withEvent:` method and trigger button's action when user touches in available range? You won't need to change button frame.

Answer (score 1):

You can subclass MPVolumeView, override layoutSubviews method, on this method, find the Button and resize it.

```
- (void)layoutSubviews {
    [super layoutSubviews];

    for (UIView *view in self.subviews) {
        if (view.class == NSClassFromString(@"MPButton")){
        //Do something here
        }
    }
}
```